# Can I play unequipped on-the-table cards in combat?

Tags: munchkin

Players can put cards down on the table unequipped. If they have a one-shot card on the table, such as a loaded die or a type of grenade, can they use those cards during combat? Or, can you only play cards that are on the table when you are not in combat?

Comment: What version of munchkin are you playing? There are no rules for a "bag" of set aside cards in the base game.

Comment: Giving to charity is an important part of the game.

Comment: You are allowed to play any items (including unusable or single-use items) to the table where the rest of your inventory is (for unusable items they must be turned sideways to indicate you aren't using them) and I think you may be confusing this for a "bag" of your own cards kept aside. Note that any cards you do play to the table, whether you can or can't use them, cannot be returned to your hand at any time, but they can be played from the table.

Comment: @JoeW: Avoiding giving to charity is also an important part of the game (as long as you do so within the rules): nothing says munchkin more than finding a legal way to play multiple cards as no-ops just so you don't have to give them away :)

Comment: @BenjaminCosman What I am referring to is the entire mechanic of giving to charity and this sounds like it is trying to remove that mechanic from the game rather then try and find a way to not do it.

Comment: @winterblood i'm using munchkin legends and start munchkin. in these the unequiped items on the side are refered to as your bag.

Comment: I can't find any reference to the word "bag" in the [Legends rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/legends_rules.pdf). Everything in there is either "in your hand" or "on the table".

Comment: I've edited this to use actual Munchkin terminology. Could you check if it's accurate, and stick to the terminology the rulebooks use if you need to edit? In particular, there's no "pull out of bag" mechanism in the rules, so that was confusing to parse from the question as asked.

Answer (score 9):

One-shot items you are "carrying" can be used just like ones in your hand. From the [rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf)*:

> All Items you have in play are considered “carried.” Items that are actually
>   giving you a bonus are “equipped.” You should indicate Items that are not
>   equipped by turning the cards sideways.
>
> A Treasure card that says “Usable once only” is often called a “one-shot”
>   Treasure. Most of these are **used during combat** to strengthen the munchkins
>   or the monsters, **and may be played from your hand or from the table.**
>
> Cards in play may not be returned to your hand.

Thus the main things that change when you put a one-shot card in play are

- Pro: it doesn't count against your hand limit.
- Con: other players can see you have it and can e.g. target it with steal-an-item effects.

Finally, I notice you are using the word "card" everywhere instead of "item", so I want to make sure you know the difference: an "Item" is any card with a gold cost (including "No Value"), and **only Items may be carried**. So if your hand is overfull with monsters and stuff, you'll have to give them to charity or find a different way to get rid of them.

*those are the base game rules, but to my knowledge none of the [many](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Munchkin_series) other versions and expansions significantly change the rule in question.

Comment: so do i put one-shots one the table sideways or like normal items?

Comment: Sideways. Only items that are currently "equipped", i.e. items that are (almost always) giving you a +N combat bonus / taking up a slot like Footgear, are vertical; both one-shots and pieces of equipment you are not using are sideways.